# How to compute distance between two lines (sequence of 2-coordinate points) in Julia

Tags: julia, distance

I have two functions, `y = f(x)` and `y = g(x)`, defined through `Array{Float64,2}` -- a sequence of (x, y) points.

I want to find such `f'(x) = f(x+dx) + dy` that the distance between the functions on the chart is minimal. For example, here, the distance is already quite small, but it could be even smaller.

[image]

In my particular case, the number of points in two arrays is identical, so I tried to minimise the following function (assuming p = [dx, dy]):

```
loss(p) = sum(abs2, mapslices(x -> x .- p, f .- g, dims=2))
```

But, apparently, this doesn't work well. Also, it would be nice to be able to work with arrays of different sizes.

Comment: can you please give a fully reproducible example? Note that as you are changing `dx` you are changing the domain of one function, so you should specify how you want the extrapolation to be performed.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński let's say I defined `f = [-2 4; -1 1; 0 0; 1 1; 2 4]` and `g = [0 0; 0.5 -0.75; 1 -1; 2 0; 1 3]` (both are simple parabolas); I want the loss function to define the distance so that an optimisation algorithm would discover that these functions closely match (in fact, perfectly match) if dx, dy = 1, -1. Linear interpolation is enough for my needs. However, I don't want to *extrapolate* beyond either one of the lines.

Comment: If you do not want to extrapolate and want curves x-axis to match then you do not need any optimization for it - just select `dx` so that the extrema of both curves match and then adjust `dy`. However, you probably want something else - that is why I am asking. Note that without an additional information the optimal solution will be to shift one curve so that its rightmost point coincides with the leftmost point of the other curve and no additional intersection happens (you ruled out extrapolation). Then you have a perfect fit on one point - but this is also probably not what you want.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński seems that Julia's optimisation frameworks don't allow to control the x-vars depending on the parameters, that my requirement "never extrapolate, only try to fit between points that both f and g define" needs. So I succumbed to extrapolation. See my answer below.

Comment: As commented above the condition "never extrapolate, only try to fit between points that both f and g define" leads to an optimal solution when the shift is such that the set of points that both `f` and `g` define has 1 element. You need to add some additional condition e.g. how big the overlap of `f` and `g` must be (or extrapolate).

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński interesting, though this is very unintuitive. Let's say the overlap should be > 50% of the shorter line.

Comment: Yes - it is unintuitive, but this is the crucial issue with using optimization in general - it does not know what is intuitive. I will write down what you would need to do to get the result you want (but it requires several packages and I do not have the time right now to write everything down as a workable code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@leventov, I have thought about this solution using Optim, which minimizes the vector along one curve with the minimum distances to the second. Arbitrary array lengths allowed and there is no need to interpolate/extrapolate.

```
using Optim, LinearAlgebra, Plots, Printf

function costf(x0)
    n, m = length(x1), length(x2)
    d = fill(Inf,n,1)
    for (ux, uy, i) in zip(x1, y1, 1:n)
        for (vx, vy) in zip(x2, y2)
            dij = norm([ux - vx - x0[1], uy - vy - x0[2]])
            dij < d[i] ? d[i] = dij : nothing
        end
    end
    return sum(d .^0.5)   # better metric for this problem
end

# x1, y1 = [-2.; -1; 0; 1; 2; 3], [4.; 1; 0; 1; 4; 9]
# x2, y2 = [0.; 0.5; 1; 2; 1], [0.; -0.75; -1; 0; 3]
x1 = -2:0.1:2;  y1 = x1 .^2
z = [exp(im*i/36*2pi) for i in 0:36]
x2, y2 = pi .+ 0.5*real(z), exp(1) .+ 0.5*(1.0 .+ imag(z))
x0 = [-2.0, -1.0]
res = optimize(costf, x0)
x0 = Optim.minimizer(res)

str = "Optim shift: dx= " * @sprintf("%.2f",x0[1]) * ", dy= " * @sprintf("%.2f",x0[2])
plot(x1,y1, color=:cyan, labels= "Input curve-1", legend=:topleft, aspectratio=1)
plot!(x2,y2, color=:blue, labels= "Input curve-2")
plot!(x2 .+ x0[1], y2 .+ x0[2], color=:red, labels= str)
```

[image: Fig.1 Optim-shifted curve]
[image: Fig.2 Optim-shifted circle]

Answer (score 4):

So the steps you would need to take is:

1. find the range of `dx` that will ensure at least 50% overlap of the curves
2. define both curves, call them `f` and `g`, using `interpolate` (without `extrapolate`) from Interpolations.jl using the points you have
3. define a function that will calculate the aggregate distance between them; the easiest would be to use QuadGK.jl with the range of integration based on `dx` and the range of curves (so that we integrate without extrapolating, call the ends of this range `xmin` and `xmax`): `quadgk(x -> (f(x)-g(x+dy)+dy)^2, xmin, xmax))`; make it a function of `dx` and `dy`
4. then use e.g. Optim.jl to find optimal `dx` and `dy` (with the constraint on `dx`)

Answer (score 1):

One solution that I came up with (not sure how optimal is it):

```
using Interpolations, LsqFit

etp = extrapolate(interpolate((fx,), fy, Gridded(Linear())), Line())

model(x, p) = collect(map(i -> etp[i], x.+p[1])).+p[2]

fit = curve_fit(model, gx, gy, [0.0, 0.0])
res = coef(fit) # outputs an array like [dx, dy]
```

Also, this solution actually does extrapolate outside of the lines. I didn't find a way to change the fitting range depending on the parameters.